# Disabling certain UIViews from touches

Tags: objective-c

I have a class called TileView which extends UIView.  In another view I create 9 TileView objects and display them on the screen.  Below is an example of 1 of them

```
tile1 = [[TileView alloc]
             initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,20, 100, 150)
             withImageNamed:@"tile1.png"
             value: 1
             isTileFlipped: NO];
```

A user can touch any of the tiles.  When a tile is touched it is "turned over" - the image is named to a plain brown tile and `isTileFlipped` is set to 'YES'.  Now comes the part I'm stuck on:  There is a confirm button.

When the confirm button is pressed, it takes all the tiles that are flipped and adds them to an array called `acceptedTiles`.  After confirm is pressed I need to make sure that the tiles in `acceptedTiles` cannot be pressed or interacted with.  I am at a loss as to what would be the best way to do this.  Here is `touchesBegan` so you can get an idea of what is happening.

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

int currentTileCount = [(BoxView *)self.superview getTileCount];
int currentTileValue = [self getTileValue];
int tilecount;

if (!isFlipped) {
    [image setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tileflipped.png"]];
    isFlipped = YES;
    tilecount = currentTileCount + currentTileValue;
    [(BoxView *)self.superview setTileCount:tilecount];
    [(BoxView *)self.superview addToArray:self index:currentTileValue-1];
}

else {
    [image setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageNamed]];
    isFlipped = NO;
    tilecount = currentTileCount - (int)currentTileValue;
    [(BoxView *)self.superview setTileCount:tilecount];
    [(BoxView *)self.superview removeFromArray: currentTileValue-1];
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is the tiles not to be interacted with, surely simply:

```
for (UIView *tile in acceptedTiles) {
    [tile setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
}
```

If that doesn't meet your requirements, please elaborate. It seems perfect for you.

Comment: I would assume that this would go at the beginning of touchesBegan?

Comment: Nevermind, that worked perfectly.  I had tried to do this sort of thing before but implemented it wrong.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't want to change your code too much you could check if the view was added to `acceptedTiles` before you do anything else in `touchesBegan:withEvent`, and if it was just return.

However, I wonder why you aren't using a `UITapGestureRecognizer` here instead? If you did you could set a delegate that implemented the `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:` method where you could check if the view was in `acceptedTiles` there instead of mixing it in with your other tap recognition logic.